# Git fetch command syntax

Tags: git

I am reading the git fetch command from this link : http://gitref.org/remotes/#fetch

It says the syntax as : `git fetch [alias]` Not sure what to put in alias

This is what git looks like when i do the `git branch`

```
* branch1
  branch2
  branch3
```

Any help on this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you are learning git, instead of the plain reference that doesn't explain much, i recommend to start here: http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial and here: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the name of the configured [remote repositories](http://gitref.org/remotes/) in there

Do `git remote -v` to see a list of the available remote repos you have

Each remote repo you have can either be referenced by its full url or by the alias assigned to it.

By default the first repo you clone from gets the alias `origin`, so if you have only ever cloned from 1 remote repo then you will want to use the command

```
git fetch origin
```

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch origin --all --prune`

To a view the names of your remotes you can use `git remote -v` or see the list in your .git/config files. usually there will be one remote named origin

It will automatically fetch all your remotes and will remove the deleted branches/tags.  You will then see the list of the new/removed tags/branches.